# How to share weights in weight between two lstm using tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I want to share weights between two lstm (or a bi-directional-lstm) . Say, I define 2 lstms:

```
with tf.variable_scope("lstm_1") as _scope:
    output_fw, output_state_fw = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell = lstm_cell1,...)

with tf.variable_scope("lstm_2") as _scope:
        output_fw, output_state_fw = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell = lstm_cell2,...)
```

How can I share weights between `lstm_1` and `lstm_2`? What if let `lstm_cell1=lstm_cell2`, is that right? If not, what should I do? thx.

Comment: Well you wrote your code. Why not try it out? In my opinion this should work. Als, have a look at keras. This is an api which works perfectly fine with tensorflow an make stuff like weight sharing, freezing layers  . . . much easier.

Comment: @dennis-ec I'll look at keras.

Comment: Weights are not shared between LSTM layers. They are shared across time-steps in one LSTM layer.